# TensorRT with CTC layers

Tags: tensorrt

I want to optimize my model using tensorRT, However, the CTC layer in my model is not supported by tensorRT. Have someone succeeded in optimizing CTC layer with tensorRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do this in two steps, firstly using TensorRT to get the probability logits, and then using a C++ CTC decoder to decode the logits.

As the decoding of CTC is suitable for CPU, and also I manage to use GPU to get the batches of logits and enqueue each batch of logit to a CPU CTC decoding queue while the GPU is running. So in this way, the CPU and GPU can run parallelly. A C++ implementation of the CTC decoder can be found in Github or from the Tensorflow repository.